# Using ascii in str_replace

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working on a R package that has a function for replacing characters like ü,ä, etc.
If I check the package, I get the warning:

> Portable packages must use only ASCII characters in their R code,
> except perhaps in comments.
> Use \uxxxx escapes for other characters.

The function contains

```
  n <- str_replace_all(n, c('ü' = 'ue', 'ï' = 'ie', "ä" = 'ae','ö' = 'oe'))
```

I tried replacing the ü with "\u00fc" and the same thing for the others. But this doesn't work.

```
str_replace("uüe", \\u00cf, "ue")
str_replace("uüe", *\\u00cf", "ue")
str_replace("uüe", <+u00cf>, "ue")
```

Any idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you're using the package `stringr`. That does allow using and manipulating non-ASCII chars.

For example:

```
vec <- "ärmlich nicht über den wolken, höchstens hïmmlisch"
```

Set the names of the strings you want to replace with `setNames`:

```
ref <- setNames(c("ue", "ie", "ae", "oe"),
                c("ü", "ï", "ä", "ö"))
```

Feed this set into the `str_replace_all`operation:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(vec, ref)
[1] "aermlich nicht ueber den wolken, hoechstens hiemmlisch"
```

Comment: although this is a nice compact way of writing it, it is not the solution to my problem. I want to use the ASCII codes, to get rid of the warning when I use ü,ä etc. in the function, I get a warning when checking my package.